# is there function in pandas equivalent to MATCH function in excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, excel-formula

a function that searches for a specified item in a range of cells, and then returns the relative position of that item in the range, in pandas?

Match function in excel which returns 4

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stack()` function on the dataframe

`df[df.isin(["TRUE"])].stack()`

The above function will give you co-ordinates of the value - `TRUE` in the dataframe